# Does the method count increase when two modules have the same dependencies in their gradle files?

Tags: android, gradle

My Android project consists of two modules

```
- app
- customModule
```

`app` module depends on `customModule`.

Both modules use `AndroidAnnotations` library, declared as a dependency in their `build.gradle` files.

My question is, does the famous 65k method count increase by the double the number of methods in `AndroidAnnotations` or only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are adding in your modules the dependencies with

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.X.X'
```

gradle handles it for you and adds the same dependency only once.

Comment: by "with" you mean with `compile` or with "X.X"

Comment: It depends by which version of the support libraries you are using

Comment: So If I am using the same version of lets say RxJava in both modules, this version of RxJava will be imported only once?

Comment: @J.K. yes exactly.